# Magento, populating checkboxes fields on an admin edit form

Tags: magento

I have a form page where I am using

```
$form->addField('name', 'checkboxes', array('label' => 'check', 'name' => 'name[]',
    'values' => array(
        array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'1'),
        array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'2'),
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'3'),
        array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>'4'),
        array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>'5'),
    )
));
```

to create a list of checkboxes.

The problem is I can't figure out how to get them to populate when editing. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

I am using the checkboxes type so they display as a list instead of in separate rows in the form. If there is a way to create them as separate fields but all in one row I would love to know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$form->addField('name', 'checkboxes', array('label' => 'check', 'name' => 'name[]',
    'values' => array(
        array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'1'),
        array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'2'),
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'3'),
        array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>'4'),
        array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>'5'),
    ),
    'value' => array('1', '5'),
    // or 
    // 'checked' => array('1', '5')
));
```

Then checkboxes with values "1" and "5" will be checked. For more details you can check lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Checkboxes.php

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I also attached code  or you can follow below link for more help
    http://pastebin.com/hKMmryE9

```
Magento, populating checkboxes fields on an admin edit form
$form->addField('name', 'checkboxes', array('label' => 'check', 'name' => 'name[]',
    'values' => array(
        array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'1'),
        array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'2'),
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'3'),
        array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>'4'),
        array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>'5'),
    )
));

$form->addField('name', 'checkboxes', array('label' => 'check', 'name' => 'name[]',
    'values' => array(
        array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'1'),
        array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'2'),
        array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'3'),
        array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>'4'),
        array('value'=>'5', 'label'=>'5'),
    ),
    'value' => array('1', '5'),
    // or
    // 'checked' => array('1', '5')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Little improved and verified:

```
$fieldset->addField('payment_methods', 'checkboxes', array('label' => 'Payment Methods', 'name' => 'payment_methods[]',
'values' => array(
    array('value'=>'1', 'label'=>'Cash'),
    array('value'=>'2', 'label'=>'Paypal'),
    array('value'=>'3', 'label'=>'Authorize.Net'),
    array('value'=>'4', 'label'=>'Square'),
),
        'required' => true,
        'checked' => array('1','4'),
        'disabled' => array('1'), ////if you want
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Create $array like below
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => 1
            [label] => Value 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => 2
            [label] => Value 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => 3
            [label] => Value 3
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [value] => 4
            [label] => Value 4
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [value] => 5
            [label] => Value 5
        )
)
$fieldset->addField('checkboxes', 'checkboxes', array(


 'label'     => 'Select Value',
                          'name'      => 'checkboxes[]',
                          'values' => $array,
                          'onclick' => "",
                          'onchange' => "",
                          'disabled' => false,
                          'after_element_html' => '',
                          'tabindex' => 1
                        ));
```